# Unable to instantiate typescript class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, instantiation

I am sorry for potentially damn question.

**Problem:**

I've got the class defined in typescript as so:

```
1    class MyClass {
2        constructor() {
3            alert("MyClass instantiated!");
4        }
5    }
6    export = MyClass;
```

It's compiled into javascript as follows:

```
1    var MyClass = (function () {
2        function MyClass() {
3            var _this = this;
4            alert("MyClass instantiated!"); 
5        }
6    }
7    module.exports = MyClass
```

It is referenced from the jsp page - which also does the following:

```
<script language='javascript' src="myclass.js">
    var myclass = new MyClass();
</script>
```

Now, I've debugged it and it hits the line **1** (of compiled .js) and then exits at line number **7** of the same file.

**Question:**

Why doesn't it go in the function and exits? Am I instantiating it wrongly?

Comment: Any comments on why are there down votes?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you exported the TypeScript into a `commonjs` format (indicated by the `module.exports = MyClass` at line 7).
What you need is to compile the TypeScript into an `UMD` format, which can be accepted by the browser.
Or simply remove `export = MyClass;` from TypeScript source.

---

The working TS code:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        alert("MyClass instantiated!");
    }
}
```

will be compiled to:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        var _this = this;
        alert("MyClass instantiated!"); 
    }
}
```

Then use it on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myclass.js"></script>
<script>
    var myclass = new MyClass();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, but the above doesn't suit eater. As I've simplified the class to indicate the problem, but the class I am struggling with is heavily used all over and acts as a starting point, therefore it needs the export, will try the umd solution.

Comment: @Sasha Try to export with `--module umd`

Answer (score 0):

You can't put context into a `script` tag that is loading another file.

Try this instead:

```
<script src="myclass.js"></script>
<script>
    var myclass = new MyClass();
</script>
```

Comment: See my updates... Also learn how to use JavaScript please :-)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. Otherwise I would of course do so.

Comment: I have compiled the class using umd format as well as separating context from the reference, continuing the research ...

Comment: @Sasha have you found out anything new in the meantime?

Comment: No, done it a different way. Instantiating a class in .ts file rather.